# Execute a query on foodmart_mysql.sql file in ubuntu and python

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute a query on the foodmart database in command line on Ubuntu, or better in python, if possible:

http://pentaho.dlpage.phi-integration.com/mondrian/mysql-foodmart-database

I tried `mysql -uroot -p <foodmart_mysql.sql` and I got `ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected`. I searched for this error and I found that I need to check for 'USE databsename`or something like this in the`sql`file and make sure that it is not there. However, there is not any`USE` command in the file.

I appreciate any help or comment.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are going to Restore some `.sql` file.

Here's the code in your command line:

```
mysql -u UsernameHere -p YourPasswordHere dbnamehere < "D:\sample.sql"
```

Before that locate the directory of your mysql first something like:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\bin`

Make sure that this directory the mysql.exe is located.

then input the code above.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My question is what is `dbnamehere`? Also, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: It is your `database name` from your mysql server. you have to `create a database name` first before you execute restore. Even you are using ubuntu. the Script is all the same. Your problem from above is you don't have a database created from your mysql server. That is why its returns you an error.

Comment: I created a db by `CREATE DATABASE temp;` and then entered `mysql -uUsernameHere -pYourPasswordHere temp < foodmart_mysql.sql`and did not get the error, but nothing happened. So, how can I see the list of the tables, or execute some queries?

Comment: run `show databases` then `use yourDBnameCreated` then `show tables`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the database name in the command. Use this command

```
mysql -u root database_name < foodmart_mysql.sql -p
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem was I did not had any databese. Using `CREATE DATABASE temp;`, I created one and now I am trying to figure out running queries in python by `sqlite`, which is almost done.